# Why does this WPF Binding fail to recognise a Tuple sub-object?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got this WPF binding:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrderExclusionConverter}">
    <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
    <Binding Path="." />
</MultiBinding>
```

In which "DataContext" is a `Tuple<Order, bool>` (Order is an entity framework object).

When I step into the converter and try and grab the values, I only really want the Order: I'm not interested in the bool value. Elsewhere in the XAML I can use this C# style notation to get the bool from the Tuple:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Item2, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

However if I do that in my Multibinding:

```
<Binding Path="DataContext.Item1" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}" />
```

Then inside the converter, the value array has the `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` for that object. This has the same effect (not that I expected it to work, just messing about):

```
<Binding Path="DataContext[0]" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}" />
```

However, if I do this:

```
<Binding Path="DataContext.Item1.ID" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}" />
```

Then the value array contains the expected int value - the ID of the bound object.

I can, of course, just pass the whole Tuple and use that, which is fine if a little clumsy. I'm just really curious about what's going on here. How come I can't pass one of the two items of the Tuple, but I can pass properties of that item?

EDIT:

I was asked about the converter. I'm using MVVM and the converter looks like this:

```
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {            
        Tuple<Order, bool> oh = (Tuple<Order, bool>)value[0];
        DateTime mc = (DateTime)value[1];

        //do stuff that sometimes returns true

        return false;
    }
```

I've been catching these errors by setting a breakpoint on the first line that sets `oh` and examining what's inside `value`. I can confirm that if you try and use `DataContext.Item1` and cast to `Order`, an exception is thrown (unsurpringly since it means value[0] is Unset).

Comment: You're saying (all else being the same) `Path="DataContext.Item1.ID"` populates a value, but `Path="DataContext.Item1"` doesn't. I don't see how that can ever be true. You're probably missing something.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Hence my question ... what am I missing? :D

Comment: I mean the facts stated in the question don't make sense.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I've just tested it again, and it behaves as stated in the question. Adding "Item1" results in an unset value. Typing ".ID" directly onto the end (so it can't be some typo in "Item1") results in my getting the ID integer. Deleting "Item1" gives me the Tuple. I would make a stripped-down version to test, but I don't have the time, unfortunately.

Comment: You're putting a breakpoint directly in the `OrderExclusionConverter.Convert`, right?

Comment: No - see the edit, where I've included the converter and how I've been debugging. Thanks for investigating - much appreciated.

Comment: Does the same happen if instead of using a tuple you use a specific DTO class which mimics the tuples two properties instead?

Comment: could you post more xaml that show the listview, multi binding and the checkbox together ?

Comment: @OmegaMan I can't test that easily. If you really think it'll be of value I could mock it up, but I'm not sure what it's going to show. Other bound objects used in that fashion work OK, so I think this is an artefact of the Tuple.

Comment: @YuliamChandra That would be a *lot* of XAML, and would probably ruin the question :) I'm certainly binding to the right objects, because if you just use DataContext, I get the expected Tuple. It's the way Item1 doesn't work that's odd.